# Add NSData to UIActivityViewController email in Swift

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have looked and looked but cannot find an answer.
I want to add NSData to an Email attachment using UIActivityViewController. The NSData attaches to Facebook but not to mail. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to attach a NSData-Object or better a file that holds these data? File attachment should be realized simplier.

Comment: Good question which may bring me on the right track!  I guess I would like to add a file which holds this data.

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was really simple. I made a class using UIActivityItemSource

```
class ShareSummary: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
...
}
```

and then added

```
let email = ShareSummary(title: title, data: data)
```

I then send the email using UIActivityViewController.